# PHP: Conditional statement with possible empty variables

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I'm creating a custom search form and when I try and sort the results I get all the objects displayed instead of the matched criteria. The reason I discovered was that some of the inputs from the form don't have a default value and when this is not declared in the conditional statement later on (for sorting) it just shows all the objects, whether the other requirements are met or not. I tried applying an OR statement with the specific variables able to be empty, but it gave the same result. Like so -

```
<?php if ($bedrooms >= $min_rooms 
          && $bedrooms <= $max_rooms 
          && $space >= $min_space 
          && $space <= $max_space 
          && $price >= $min_price 
          && $price <= $max_price 
          && $sel_type == $type 
          || $sel_type == '' 
          && $country == $sel_country 
          || $sel_country == '' ) { ?>
```

(See the last two statements)
I was thinking of checking each variable in the conditional statement before including it but it feels like unnecessary code. How would you do it?

Comment: Custom Post Types. I figure it's easier just sending the values with $_POST to the result page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `&&` operator has a higher precedence than the `||` operator, so your expression is currently grouped like this, probably not what you want:

```
($bedrooms >= $min_rooms && $bedrooms <= $max_rooms && $space >= $min_space && $space <= $max_space && $price >= $min_price && $price <= $max_price && $sel_type == $type)
||
($sel_type == '' && $country == $sel_country)
||
($sel_country == '' )
```

Try adding parentheses like this to achieve correct grouping:

```
($bedrooms >= $min_rooms && $bedrooms <= $max_rooms && $space >= $min_space && $space <= $max_space && $price >= $min_price && $price <= $max_price && ($sel_type == $type || $sel_type == '') && ($country == $sel_country || $sel_country == '') )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your expression may fail as the `&&` operator has a higher [precedence](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) than the `||` operation. That means an expression like this:

```
… && $sel_type == $type || $sel_type == ''
```

is equivalent to this (operator precedence highlighted by using parentheses):

```
(… && $sel_type == $type) || $sel_type == ''
```

To fix that put the `||` expressions in parentheses:

```
$bedrooms >= $min_rooms && $bedrooms <= $max_rooms && $space >= $min_space && $space <= $max_space && $price >= $min_price && $price <= $max_price && ($sel_type == $type || $sel_type == '') && ($country == $sel_country || $sel_country == '')
```

Additionally, your expression is probably easier to read and to maintain if you use some helper functions like a `between` function:

```
function between($val, $min, $max) {
    return $min <= $val && $val <= $max;
}
```

Then your expression reads:

```
between($bedrooms, $min_rooms, $max_rooms) && between($space, $min_space, $max_space) && between($price, $min_price, $max_price) && ($sel_type == $type || $sel_type == '') && ($country == $sel_country || $sel_country == '')
```